# .NET Expression SDK LiveJob Authentication

Tags: .net, authentication, sdk, expression, encoder

I'm trying to stream a live feed to a Publishing Point but keep getting 'Access is Denied' errors.  I can do this just fine in the Expression Encoder application (using a valid username and password).  But when I try to use the same username/password in my custom app, I get that error.  I've tried pre-connecting without credentials, which fires the AcquireCredentials event.

So I know its connecting to the server just fine, but my user credentials are being denied through my custom app.  Any idea what the problem is?  Here's a snippet of my code (if it helps):

```
LiveJob job = new LiveJob();

LiveDevice audioDevice = (LiveDevice)cmbAudioDevices.SelectedItem;
LiveDevice videoDevice = (LiveDevice)cmbVideoDevices.SelectedItem;

LiveDeviceSource liveSource = job.AddDeviceSource(videoDevice, audioDevice);
job.ActivateSource(liveSource);

System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef h = new System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef(panel1, panel1.Handle);

job.DeviceSources[0].PreviewWindow = new PreviewWindow(h)
{
    Visible = true
};

System.Security.SecureString password = new System.Security.SecureString();
foreach (char letter in txtPassword.Text.ToCharArray())
    password.AppendChar(letter);

job.OutputFormat = new WindowsMediaPublishingPointOutputFormat()
{
    PublishingPoint = new Uri(txtPublishPoint.Text)
    UserName = txtUsername.Text,
    Password = password
};

job.PreConnectPublishingPoint();
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a server permissions issue.  Was able to install a second box connect just fine.